# JPEG image pixels quality

Tags: image, jpeg

Editing JPEG image and saving drops image quality level in quantization tables. If I add new object to original image, new object quality level will drop equally with original image? Example, original image saved with new object "Happy Christmas", original image pixels quality drops to 90%, does it effect new object pixels quality as well - 90%?

Image quality 100%:
[image]

New object added "Happy Christmas" text. Image quality 90%:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of "quality level" in JPEG. If you're quantization tables are changing that is entirely the function of whatever encoder you are using.

You should note that JPEG does not work well with images where there are abrupt changes in color (as you have in the second image). That is something more suitable for PNG.

Comment: When optimizing jpeg image where is no thing like quality level?

Comment: Quality level does not exist in JPEG. Some encoders simplify quantization by having quality settings but there is no guarantee of consistently across implementations and a JPEG encoder need not do it that way or even have any knowledge of quality settings.